# Glassmorphism in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, blur

has anyone  an idea of how to implement  the glassmorphism  design in jetpack compose (or maybe xml if there is no way in compose)?
The main problem I had while trying  was to give the area behind a surface a blur-effect.

Thx in advance

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/ComposeDesigner/GlassmorphismOnCompose. But it only works for Android 12+.

Comment: In fact this has the same issue , the area behind the card is not blurred. I tried the code with another bg

Comment: Check this, no API restrictions... https://medium.com/@jahongir9779/glassmorphism-in-jetpack-compose-for-scrolling-item-b0c5824b55d0

Comment: Oh, thx! Will definitely try it